# não consigo logar no Magento 1.9.2

Tags: magento

Estou com um problema na pagina de login do Admin, insiro os dados para conectar e nada acontece, não sou redirecionado, não aparece nenhum erro e os dados nem são verificados. Estava funcionando perfeitamente,mas hoje o mySQL não "startava" e precisei restaurar a pasta data, o que achei estranho pois não havia alterado nada, a unica coisa diferente que fiz foi instalar o WinHTTrack.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você restaurou a pasta `data` do mysql? Então provavelmente perdeu os dados (espero que tenha um backup). Sobre o não iniciar do mysql (que foi o que desencadeou o problema) ao invés de sair deletando as coisas olhe no log, mas é preciso habilitar o log primeiro ([How can I start and check my MySQL log?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9871808/1518921)), acesse a sua pasta `./bin` (supondo que seja windows) pelo `cmd`, algo como:

```
cd C:\wwamp\mysql\bin
```

> Se tiver backup da pasta `./data` restaure ele neste momento

Depois digite `mysql` no input do cmd e aperte Enter. Então execute isto:

```
mysql> SET GLOBAL general_log = 'ON';
```

Se falhar tente editar o arquivo `my.conf` aonde fica algo como:

```
# The MySQL server
[mysqld]
port        = 3306
socket      = /.tmp/mysql.sock
skip-external-locking
key_buffer_size = 16K
max_allowed_packet = 1M
table_open_cache = 4
sort_buffer_size = 64K
read_buffer_size = 256K
read_rnd_buffer_size = 256K
net_buffer_length = 2K
thread_stack = 128K
sync_binlog = 0
```

E adicione isto:

```
general_log = 1
```

Verifique no gerenciador de tarefas se tem algum processo do mysql, finalize todos eles (ou reiniciei o Windows).

Após isto será gerado um arquivo de log na pasta `./data` chamado `mysql.log`, confira a causa do problema que havia afetado inicialização do mysql.

Comment: Sim, faço backup antes de qualquer alteração e agora esta tudo ok, mas muito obrigado por usa resposta, com certeza já saberei onde procurar caso ocorra novamente.

Answer (score 0):

Existem alguns fatores que influenciam no login do admin, o mais comum é o caminho do cookie no banco está incorreto.

Verificar:

```
UPDATE core_config_data set value "www.seudominio.com.br" where path = 'web/cookie/cookie_domain';
```